# UserNotification AppInfo throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications

I want to use UWP library in WPF, so I installed Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts.

```cs
IReadOnlyList<UserNotification> notifs = await listener.GetNotificationsAsync(NotificationKinds.Toast);

foreach (UserNotification notif in notifs)
{
    try
    {
        var appDisplayName = notif.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;

        DateTimeOffset creationTime = notif.CreationTime;
        uint notificationId = notif.Id;
        
        NotificationBinding toastBinding = notif.Notification.Visual.GetBinding(KnownNotificationBindings.ToastGeneric);

        IReadOnlyList<AdaptiveNotificationText> textElements = toastBinding.GetTextElements();

        string titleText = textElements.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;

        string bodyText = string.Join("\n", textElements.Skip(1).Select(t => t.Text));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it throws a `NotImplementedException`. But when I comment out the line `var appDisplayName = notif.AppInfo.DisplayInfo.DisplayName;`, the program runs successfully. I have also packaged WPF into .msix, but still cannot execute it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked UserNotificationListener class is supported in desktop apps?